# Destructor for a singly Linked List in C++

Tags: c++, memory, memory-leaks, linked-list

Trying to create a destructor for my singly linked list class. The close consists of a a First and Last variable. And then a Node structure.

The Node structure looks like this:

```
struct node
{
    TYPE value;
    node * next;
    node * last;
};
```

My current code in the destructor is this:

```
queue::~queue(){

    node* temp;
    while (first != NULL)
    {
        temp = first->next;
        delete first;
        first = temp;
    }
}
```

I attempt to use a while look to loop through the program, and delete each node before moving onto the next one. However, when I run a valgrind check on it.. I have a ton of memory leaks. I can't really figure out how else I should be deleting everything.

Comment: Maybe you should try to figure out why there are memory leaks: find something that leaks, then find out why it doesn't get deleted.

Comment: Are your sure your destructor gets called?

Comment: @marcinj I was assuming a constructor would always get called upon the program using the class ending.. is that not true?

Comment: @immibis its obivously the node objects leaking.. trying to figure out specifically why theya re leaking

Comment: @JoeCaraccio Part A: How are they supposed to be destroyed? Part B: Why is that not happening?

Comment: @immibis thats what I am trying to figure out :/

Comment: I think that the leaking is elsewhere.